# How to recreate the spaghettification process around blackhole in blender?

Tags: animation, physics

I have been using blender from about a year and working on Blender for 3d Scientific Animations. I am very much fascinated about how NASA and ESO create because of animations of Astronomy. Can they be created using a blender?

In this thread, I am specifically asking about the latest ESO animation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKCp-1OGGP4

In this animation, the star is ripping apart and the black hole is eating it. How can I stretch the sphere like this in the blender?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the lattice-modifier!

Outside of the funnel-shaped lattice, the sphere is undeformed...
[image]

...then it gets sucked in...
[image]

...and spaghettifies!
[image]

Make the lattice a bit more detailed and curved, and you should get what you need.

The accretion disk and jets can be made with particle systems. As for the gravity-lensing, there are quite a lot of tutorials out there that deal with making "Interstellar"-like black holes

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way: Create a sphere for your sun, another for your hole. Create a curve, hook its tip to an empty, parent the star to the same empty, parent the empty to the black hole. In the *Properties panel > Object Data*, give your curve a *Bevel Depth*, give it a *Taper Object* (the second curve) to make the tail radius shrink towards the black hole, enable the *Map Taper* option:

[image]

Now you can animate everything, make the sun and its tail rotate around the blackhole, keyframe the curve values, for example its *Bevel Start* and *End*:

[image]

And of course add some particles (or smoke?).

Comment: Hey, Thank you for such an easy hack. Now, my question is: "How will I continue the animation after this i.e star mesh moving on the same path and getting dump into the black hole (for the reference, check the animations in two answers above)?"

Comment: you can rotate and scale the whole thing (sun + trail), it's just a matter of could parent/child settings

Answer (score 0):

Using a particle system and a curve guide:

[image]

Add a particle system to the sun. Tune the amount of particles and lifetime. Set the render to an object. Add an effector collection. Turn off gravity.

[image]

Add a curve in the effector collection and move its start/end to match the sun and the black hole. Set it as curve guide in the physics tab. Tune the distance so that it contains the sun volume.

[image]

Eventually, hook the curve starting point to the sun and animate this last one in position and scale, to make it vanish.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but wouldn't it put the load on particle system on the system?

Comment: @MuneebAli Hi, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean that particle systems have huge cache which can slow down the PC I guess.